# Wht is the difference between Q.all() and Promise.prototype.all() methods?

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I'm trying to understand how promises work, so general idea is quite clear, but currently I'm stuck with `all()` method. I know, it used to make a promise for an array of other promises, which will be resolved when all promises from the array will resolved or will be rejected when any of the promises from the array will rejected. Here is my code snippet:

```
var qu = require('q');
var proArr = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var tmpDef = qu.defer();

    (function(index, tmpDef) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('Timeout ' + index + ' has triggered!');
            tmpDef.resolve();
        }, (i + 1) * 1000);
        proArr.push(tmpDef.promise);
    })(i, tmpDef);
}

qu.all(proArr).then(function() { 
    console.log('All timeouts has passed with Q.all()!');
    return 'some result';
});
qu.defer().promise.all(proArr).then(function() { 
    console.log('All timeouts has passed with promise.all()!');
    return 'some result';
});
```

For this snippet a promise, which returned by `qu.all()` method will be resolved when all timeouts will be triggered, but a promise, which returned by `qu.defer().promise.all()` method will stay in pending state even if all timeouts will be triggered. So what the method `Promise.prototype.all()` have to be used for? And how it differs from `Q.all()` method?

Also I've looked in Q library sources, and here is a code for `Promise.prototype.all()` method:

```
Promise.prototype.all = function () {
    return all(this);
};
```

As I can understand, this method calls `Q.all()` with an instance of current promise as an argument, but why? Don't the method `Q.all()` have to accept an array of promises? So I'll be very appreciated for clarification of all this moments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Don't the method `Q.all()` have to accept an array of promises?

No, in fact the `Q.all` method also can take a promise for an array of promises. You can see that [in the code](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/79e5b717d7d54f21fe27d1b53f1b8b70eaab0219/q.js#L1561) well, it does call [`Q.when`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promise-methods) on the input. This might seem a bit useless, but it's a more forgiving API and apparently simiplifies the implementation of `Promise.prototype.all`.

> What is the difference between `Q.all()` and `Promise.prototype.all()`?

Let's get back to our simpler mental model. `Q.all` is a static function that takes an array of promises and returns you a promise for an array of all results.

The `.all` prototype method is simply convenience. Instead of writing

```
….then(Q.all).…
```

you can use

```
….all().…
```

in a promise chain - these are exactly equivalent. Notice that the `.all` prototype method does not take any parameters - it does get the array from promise it is called on.

> a promise, which returned by `Q.defer().promise.all(proArr)` method will stay in pending state even if all timeouts will be triggered

Yes. That's for two reasons:

- `Q.defer().promise` is a promise that never resolves (and since you've thrown away the deferred, you never can). The chain just doesn't even advance to the `.all(…)` invocation.
- As established above, the prototype method you're calling here doesn't take any arguments. The `proArr` is simply ignored.

If you want to use it, you can use the following though:

```
Q(proArr).all().…
```

Comment: So both `qu(proArr).all()` and `qu.all(proArr)` have equal meaning - they return a promise for specified array of promises?

Comment: Yes. And if you'd want to let it wait, you could do `Q(proArr).delay(…).all()` (or `Q.all(Q(proArr).delay(…))`).